# Joomla contact category in database

Tags: joomla3.0

I see that in the Joomla table "#_contact_details" the Contact Category to which the user belongs is referenced in the table as "catid". Can anyone tell me in which table I can find these Contact categories (=catid)?

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

no answers...?!

ok, found it myself and post the answer, in case someone else finds this useful later.

The "Contact Categories" are stored (together with the "Article categories" and other component categories) in the "_categories" table.